# Como fazer um max + 1 com lambda ou linq, mas com tabelas a partir do nada, tudo null

Tags: c#

Fiz esse método e outras tentativas. Com a tabela preenchida, ok, mas com a tabela sem dados, fica dando erro:

```
public int GeraIdBalanca()
{
    int chave = 0;
    var obj = contexto.Balancas.Max().IdBalanca;
    if (obj == 0)
        chave = 1;
    else
        chave = obj + 1;
    return chave;
}
```

Tentei com a tabela com informações, eu consigo trazer o ID, mas com a tabela zerada, recém criada me dá erro.

Comment: Não sei dizer até porque acho que falta contexto (sem querer fazer trocadilho com a variável), mas este código pode ser escrito assim: `contexto.Balancas.Max().IdBalanca + 1` e dá o mesmo resultado.

Comment: se não houver nenhum registro no banco, `Max()` retornaria null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código inteiro pode ser escrito assim

```
public int GeraIdBalanca() => contexto.Balancas.Max()?.IdBalanca + 1 ?? 1;
```

O seu problema é porque é necessário checar se o retorno de `Max` não é nulo antes de tentar acessar a propriedade `IdBalanca`.

```
var obj = contexto.Balancas.Max()?.IdBalanca ?? 1;
```

Se estiver usando  o Entity Framework, já te adianto que a sua abordagem não funciona e nem faz sentido.

No EF, o método precisaria ser assim

```
public int GeraIdBalanca() => contexto.Balancas.Any() ? contexto.Balancas.Max(b => b.id) + 1 : 1;
```

Ou, num método normal

```
public int GeraIdBalanca()
{
    return contexto.Balancas.Any() ? contexto.Balancas.Max(b => b.id) + 1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: isso para o C# 7 certo :)

Comment: Não, @MarconcilioSouza. C# 6.

Comment: Verdade, confundir a versão.

Comment: @LINQ, não entendi a sua implementação. Da forma que está dá o mesmo erro, mas não entendi se é um método ou o que, a primeira linha da sua resposta.

Comment: É um método. Se você está usando EF, veja o final da resposta.

Comment: Esse sua edição resolveu. Não testei ainda a segunda etapa do Marconcilio, porque a primeira eu havia feito e dá erro.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que possa ser feito assim:

```
        var obj = contexto.Balancas.Max(b => b.IdBalanca);
        int chave = (obj == null ? 1 : obj + 1);
        return chave;
```

Comment: Rovann, dá esse erro o mesmo que estava dando: `The specified method 'Domain.Entities.Balanca Max[Balanca](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Domain.Entities.Balanca])' on the type 'System.Linq.Queryable' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because no overload matches the passed arguments.`

Comment: acho que está faltando o parâmetro do método, pelo que pesquisei aqui deveria ser algo assim:  `contexto.Balancas.Max(b => b.IdBalanca);`

Comment: Vou tenta assim, mas havia feito e deu erro, mas fiz sem o ternário

Comment: Rovann, eu havia feito semelhante(sem o ternário) e não deu certo. Agora na linha `obj.IdBalanca`me dá erro em design, dizendo `int não contém uma definição para IdBalanca e não há método de extensão........`

Comment: o `Max` nesse caso está retornando um int, não sei se ele pode ser null mas basta tirar o `obj.IdBalanca` e deixar apenas o `obj`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma solução Default para quando sua tabela não tive dados.

```
public int GeraIdBalanca()
{
    return contexto.Balancas.Select(m => m.IdBalanca).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max() + 1;
}
```